# Why is Gradle / / Sonar Jacoco looking for dir and also project?

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

Background:

We have two subprojects each with many sub-sub-projects. The root project is an empty parent. We have one project that is strictly for the flyway plugin. Often times names do not match directories. For perspective, settings.gradle is 219 lines and roughly half of those are projects.

So I'm getting this error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The base directory of the module ':commons:sitewidget' does not exist: /dev/abc/commons/:commons:sitewidget

Here is the question: How did the SonarQube Gradle plugin build that path? By this, I mean `/dev/abc/commons/:commons:sitewidget` which doesn't exist. The actual path is `/dev/abc/commons/sitewidget`.

If I can find a way to force it to build the path correctly, I may be able to work around other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by the [Sonar Source Team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534773/julien-h-sonarsource-team) with https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-14 and a bugfix release 2.0.1 was deployed on Gradle plugin portal.

Comment: Yes. I spotted it today.